# caret deepnet produces same value for all predictions

Tags: r, deep-learning, neural-network, r-caret

I am very new to deep learning. I trained a neural net using the packages `deepnet` and `caret`. For this regression problem `caret`uses a sigmoid function as activation function and a linear one as output function.
I preprocessed the predictors using `preprocess = "range"` (which I thought normalizes the predictors).

```
library(caret)
library(deepnet)
set.seed(123, kind = "Mersenne-Twister", normal.kind = "Inversion")

# create data
dat <- as.data.frame(ChickWeight)
dat$vari <- sample(LETTERS, nrow(dat), replace = TRUE)
dat$Chick <- as.character(dat$Chick)

preds <- dat[1:100,2:5]
response <- dat[1:100,1]
vali <- dat[101:150,]

# change format of categorical predictors to one-hot encoded format
dmy <- dummyVars(" ~ .", data = preds)
preds_dummies <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = preds))


# specifiy trainControl for tuning mtry and with specified folds
control <- caret::trainControl(search = "grid", method="repeatedcv", number=3, 
                               repeats=2, 
                               savePred = T)

# tune hyperparameters and build final model
tunegrid <- expand.grid(layer1 = c(5,50),
                        layer2 = c(0,5,50), 
                        layer3 = c(0,5,50),
                        hidden_dropout = c(0, 0.1), 
                        visible_dropout = c(0, 0.1))

model <- caret::train(x = preds_dummies,
                      y = response, 
                      method="dnn",
                      metric= "RMSE", 
                      tuneGrid=tunegrid, 
                      trControl= control,
                      preProcess = "range"
)
```

When I predict using the validation set with the tuned neural network model, it produces only one prediction value despite of various input predictors.

```
# predict with validation set
# create dummies
dmy <- dummyVars(" ~ .", data = vali)
vali_dummies <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = vali))
vali_dummies <- vali_dummies[,which(names(vali_dummies) %in% model$finalModel$xNames)]
# add empty columns for categorical preds of the one used in the model (to have the same matix)
not_included <- setdiff(model$finalModel$xNames, names(vali_dummies))
vali_add <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(0, length(not_included)*nrow(vali_dummies)), 
                                 nrow = nrow(vali_dummies),
                                 ncol = length(not_included))
)
# change names
names(vali_add) <- not_included
# add to vali_dummies
vali_dummies <- cbind(vali_dummies, vali_add)
# put it in the same order as preds_dummies (sort the columns)
vali_dummies <- vali_dummies[names(preds_dummies)]

# normalize also the validation set
pp = preProcess(vali_dummies, method = c("range"))
vali_dummies <- predict(pp, vali_dummies)

# save obs and pred for predictions with the outer CV out-of-fold test set
temp <- data.frame(obs = vali[,1],
                   pred = caret::predict.train(object = model, newdata = vali_dummies))
temp
```

When I am using the Boston data set from the `MASS` package where no categorical predictors are present, I get slightly different prediction values for all the different input predictors of the validation set.
How can I fix this and create a neural network which predicts "different" predictions when using numeric as well as categorical predictors? What else besides normalization should I try?

Comment: what happens if you do not normalize the validation set?

Comment: When I don't normalize, I get even worse predictions. They all have the same value and with a bigger difference to the observations. The values get better, when I use `preprocess = c("center", "scale")` instead of `range`. This scales the predictors between -1 and 1 instead of 0 to 1 as range does. Then in both data sets (Chickweight and Boston) I get predictions that are slightly different from each other and that are closer to the observed values. In my real data set, this still produces the same prediction value regardless of the input, although this value is a bit closer to observations.

Comment: When I don't normalize the validation set, I get different predictions that are sometimes close to the observations. But it makes no sense to me because the neural network is trained on the normalized predictors, so the predictors in the validation set need to be normalized as well, or am I missing something? Is the whole model only built from different weights and the cost function and the unnormalized validation set is affected in the same way as the normalized predictors were affected within carets tuning?

Comment: I did not mean to skip normalizing the train set, I meant just normalize the train and do not normalize the test set. Caret predict should handle normalization correctly and apply it to the test set. Normalization of the test set  is based on the train set. When you apply it independently you get scrambled predictions.

Comment: I tried it again with `"range"` and there I get the exact same prediction value when I normalize the validation predictors and when I don't normalize them. It seems to have no effect while using `"range"`. With `preprocess = c("center", "scale")` I get different predictions regardless of standardizing the validation set. Where in carets documentation can I read about the validation set being affected by the preProcess settings in the same way as the training set?

Comment: I will take a look at you example when I get some time. I can't find the appropriate documentation for preprocessing being applied to test set, however I found this answer on CV from the author of caret [topepo = Max Khun](https://github.com/topepo)  [about it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81609/is-preprocessing-needed-before-prediction-using-finalmodel-of-randomforest-with). And from my own experience preprocessing is definitely automatically applied to the predicted set when using `predict.train`

Comment: Ok thank you. I get an RMSE of 52.39 using preprocessing with `range` on the validation set. I get the same RMSE without any preprocessing on validation set, since it produces the exact same predictions. But when using `preProcess = c("center", "scale")` during training then applying the same to the validation set, I get a RMSE of 58.14 and without additional preprocessing of vali it is 51.9. So `center` and `scale` behave differently than `range` when applying additional preprocessing to the validation set.

Comment: Just wanted to inform you that I had no luck getting to the bottom of this. I do not get any variance in the predictions no mater what I tried. Perhaps try some other neural net library. On the other hand your code can be largely simplified regarding the dummy variable creation but that has nothing to do with your question.